Sudden Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 1 with SpotifyWebAPI
I am developing a .NET application using Spotify via SpotifyAPI-NET (I am quite new to C#).
I am getting this error when calling spotify.Player.PausePlayback()
Weirdly I was not getting this error a few weeks ago, even with the version of the code I am sharing in this question, and I have just suddenly started getting it. Here is the version of it that was working and is now giving this weird error:
static (Uri, string) InitializeSpotify()
{
    var (verifier, challenge) = PKCEUtil.GenerateCodes();
    string ClientId="MyclientId"; 
    


    var loginRequest = new LoginRequest(new Uri("https://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/"),ClientId,LoginRequest.ResponseType.Code)
    {
    CodeChallengeMethod = "S256",
    CodeChallenge = challenge,
    Scope = new[] {Scopes.PlaylistReadPrivate, Scopes.PlaylistReadCollaborative,Scopes.Streaming}
    };

    var uri = loginRequest.ToUri();
    return (uri,verifier);

}
static string GetCode(string url){
    Process.Start("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe", url);
    Console.Write("Write the code here:");
    string code = Console.ReadLine();
    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)){
        Console.WriteLine("You didn't write a code, write it again.");
        code = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    return code;
}



static async Task<SpotifyClient> GetCallback(string code,string verifier)
{

    var initialResponse = await new OAuthClient().RequestToken(
        new PKCETokenRequest("MyclientId", code, new Uri("https://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/"), verifier)
        );
    var authenticator = new PKCEAuthenticator("MyclientId", initialResponse);

    var config = SpotifyClientConfig.CreateDefault()
    .WithAuthenticator(authenticator);
    var spotify = new SpotifyClient(config);
    Console.Write("Authentication Successful...");
    return spotify;

}
static async Task Playback(){
    (Uri uri,string verifier)= InitializeSpotify();
    string code = GetCode(uri.ToString());
    SpotifyClient spotify = await GetCallback(code,verifier);
    //Controlling the playback
    
    while (true){
        Console.WriteLine();
        string state = Console.ReadLine();
        if (state=="pause"){await spotify.Player.PausePlayback();}
        if (state=="resume"){await spotify.Player.ResumePlayback();}
        if (state=="next"){await spotify.Player.SkipNext();}
        if (state=="previous"){await spotify.Player.SkipPrevious();}
        else{continue;}

    }    
}



await Playback();


I have tried using other methods and scopes such as
Scopes.UserReadPlaybackState 

together with
var playback = await spotify.Player.GetCurrentPlayback();

And that works fine. Which makes me think that maybe modification of the playback state is the problem?
Edit the full error is:
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at SpotifyAPI.Web.Http.NewtonsoftJSONSerializer.DeserializeResponse[T](IResponse response)
   at SpotifyAPI.Web.Http.APIConnector.DoSerializedRequest[T](IRequest request, CancellationToken cancel)
   at SpotifyAPI.Web.Http.APIConnector.SendAPIRequestDetailed(Uri uri, HttpMethod method, IDictionary`2 parameters, Object body, IDictionary`2 headers, CancellationToken cancel)
   at SpotifyAPI.Web.Http.APIConnector.Put(Uri uri, IDictionary`2 parameters, Object body, CancellationToken cancel)
   at SpotifyAPI.Web.PlayerClient.ResumePlayback(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Program.<<Main>$>g__Playback|0_3() in C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\Webscraping\ConsoleApp1\Authentication.cs:line 64
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\Webscraping\ConsoleApp1\Authentication.cs:line 75
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)

Edit 2, the raw response at the time of the error (looks like) it is this:
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 21:07:16.116
EndTime: 21:07:19.180
ClientToServerBytes: 618
ServerToClientBytes: 4405

This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
To view the encrypted sessions inside this tunnel, enable the Settings > HTTPS > Capture HTTPS traffic option.

A SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
SessionID:  empty
Random:     66 91 8C F3 DF CB DB 1F EB C4 AE DB 45 AE 1C 3B 45 27 A4 22 75 D4 5D 59 44 4F 57 4E 47 52 44 01
Cipher:     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [0xC02F]
CompressionSuite:   NO_COMPRESSION [0x00]
Extensions:
        extended_master_secret  empty
        renegotiation_info  00
        ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
        SessionTicket   empty

Thanks in advance!

line 1, position 1 usually means some server returned something that was not JSON in the response body, because e.g. it was an error response and the body contains the error message.  Could your server be returning an error and you are not checking for it?  Might you please [edit] your question to share the full ToString() output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

I have added the full error for it now.
I don't know? How do I check for what my server might be returning?

What Spotify library are you using?  Is it SpotifyAPI-NET?  Perhaps that library has some built-in way to inspect the raw response and request.  Or you could use something like Fiddler to inspect your web traffic.

Yes I am using SpotifyAPI-NET, I am not aware of any ways of doing that. I am trying to use Fiddler right now, just opened and executed the code with it and I have no clue what I am doing, the responses all give status of "200 connection stablished" even for the messages at the moment of the error. I have also got the raw responses at the time when the error occured aaand, what exactly should I be looking for? Which response would it be worth sharing?

It might help if you [edit] your question to include the raw response that caused the error.

Okay, I've eddited my question with one of the responses at the time of the error, I am not sure if that is the response that specifically caused the error, it's not very clear from Fiddler which response was the one that caused the error exactly. But this was the last spotify ("http://api.spotify.com:443") response I got.
